# Remove spacing between listview items

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make a ListView containing images in Android.
I want the images to be right up against each other in the list, but I can't seem to get the spacing away.

Here is my listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0.0px"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my listrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/vw01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">    

<ImageView android:id="@+id/img01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can see the spacing I am talking about here:
http://imgbucket.info/img/kad67sjsg/stackoverflow.png

Comment: This looks fine to me. Are you sure there are no transparent pixels in your images?

Comment: It looks fine to me aswell.That's what's driving me crazy :) I'm quite sure there are no transparent pixels. The image I am using is here:http://imgbucket.info/img/1dbvyxqvi/bluebrick.png

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried to put "minHeight=0dip" in your listrow's linearlayout?

Comment: I had not. It didn't work though.

Comment: Your layout xml helped me remove the black border between my items! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

I scaled the pictures down, which did the trick, so the problem wasn't even in the code.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Like I wrote the problem wasn't in the code. I scaled the image files down using an image editor.

Comment: Thanks this helped me too!