# Must I resize images downloaded from server used in listView?

Tags: android, listview, optimization, image-resizing

I have problems with lagg when scrolling and space between listItems. If anybody could give me  a hint on what's wrong with my code I would be really greatfull.

When my app starts I download all thumbnails from my server and save them like this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(uniqueName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(bytes);
fos.close();
```

All the images are 100px x 75px

ListItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pic"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp">
   </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I then load the images with asyncTask like this:

```
private Drawable d;

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
   File filePath = ctx.getFileStreamPath(fileName);
   if (filePath.exists()) {
       d = Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString());
       return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {

    if (success == 1) {
        listener.onCacheThumbCompleted(d);
    }
}
```

Finally add the image to imageView in listItem:

```
public void onCacheThumbCompleted(Drawable drawable) {

    iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

But it's not smooth at all when scrolling. Also it seems that the image does not fill the imageView completely. It's a space between the listItems even if I set the dividerHeight to 0.
[Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417946/remove-spacing-between-listview-items) and he solved it by resizing his images, but do I need to resize/scale my images to fix my problems?

Comment: yes you need to resize it acording to your requirement. also use a viewholder for smooth scrolling and performance

Comment: Resize them. My ListView runs way faster on 200 resized images, than on original ones.

Comment: I didn't thought I needed to resize them because they came in the right size from the server (100x75).

Comment: Should I resize images before saving them or when I load them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smooth `ListView` can be quite complex on Android. The best example I've found is [Shelves](https://code.google.com/p/shelves/) by Romain Guy. It features a lot of complex patterns and can be hard to digest but if you do digest everything you'll be a lot smarter when you come out on the other side :)

To list some of most important enhancements:

- Lazy load of images
- ViewHolder
- Resizing of images

You could also search for these enhancement features and implement them yourself.

Comment: I will gladly look at Shelves, thanks!
But it seems strange that I need to resize images that are the right size from the beginning. Pixel in android not same as pixel on a computer?

Comment: @Toydor sure it is but android phones come in many different sizes. If you use a fixed pixel size image you will get a weird layout.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have bigger images on my server. They are all 100x75.  So if I don't want them blurry I must use a fixed size? 
But if I use a fixed size like I do now, android still scales when populating imageView?
Sorry I'm still confused.

Comment: @Toydor for a mdpi screen you might need 100x75 px but for a xhdpi screen you'll need 200x150 px. The optimal way to do this would be to have a super high resolution image on the server and then make httpget request on appropriate size. The server needs to support this kind of feature in order for this to work but I believe there is modules and other ways to achieve this. Can you not do it on server side then you have to download highest resolution image and down sample it to the proper size on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Try using LAZYLIST/ LAZY-LOADING if you have a lot of images.